# Run MSTests using Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, mstest

I'm facing an issue running MSTests from Visual Studio Code on macOS Sierra. I have added the dependency in the project.json (`"Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework": "11.0.50727.1"`)

Also I have restored the project, meaning VS Code did download the dll file, but I still seem to be getting the error:

`The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [netcoreapp1.1]`

Does VS Code support running MSTests in the first place? If yes, where I might be going wrong?

[image]

As you can see in `ProgramTest.cs` file, it cannot find the namespace `'VisualStudio'`.

P.S: I'm new to VSCode and C#.

Comment: I guess this is still an issue today. I'm having the exact same problem.